# Optimal approach to full-text search with vue + firestore

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am coding a sort of a collaborative agenda with a serverless architecture with firestore and Vuejs. I am trying to figure out the best approach for implementing a full-text search function looking at both users and events, given the following constraints:

- small amount of documents (<5000) and concurrent users (<1000)
- reactivity (I need search-as-you-type capabilities and generally high responsiveness)
- offline availability and syncing capabilities
- reachable from either VueJs code or google cloud functions for 'back-end' purposes (I want to be able to use both search inputs and outputs for data modelling and optimizations)
- low budget (free would be fine)

Given these constraints, is a pure client-side approach like *elasticlunr* the best? Or can I go a long way with just firestore? What are the best practices in that regard?

Comment: Check the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/a6zakg/optimal_approach_to_fulltext_search_with/

Comment: @holmberd thanks for the reply, I am not interested in Algolia though as it's too expensive for my needs.